# Creating and sending two kinds of notification messages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, i18n

I wish to get rid of using switch case with statuses twice in my code. But `create_message` function will be bigger in the future, so must stay and I don't want to create messages in `send_user_push_notification` directly.

Any ideas?

```
def send_user_push_notification(order, parse_events)
  now = Time.zone.now
  case parse_events
  when 'pending'
    if send_push_notification(order.shopper_id, order, parse_events)
      order.shopper_notified_at = now
    end
  when 'handed_over'
    if send_push_notification(order.deliverer_id, order, parse_events)
      order.deliverer_notified_at = now
    end
  end
end

def send_push_notification(user_id, order, parse_events)
  Parse.publish_order_status(
    user_id,
    *parse_events,
    create_message(order, parse_events)
  )
end

def create_message(order, parse_events)
  case parse_events
  when 'pending'
    I18n.t('orders.shopper.message')
  when 'handed_over'
    I18n.t(
      'orders.deliverer.message',
       order_id: order.order_id,
       store_id: order.store_id
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the two decisions, for instance:

```
# Outside your method 
EVENT_TO_USERKIND = { pending: 'shopper', handed_over: :'deliverer' }

# Now inside your method 
user_kind = EVENT_TO_UID_METHOD[parse_events]
if user_kind && send_push_notification(order.send("#{user_kind}_id"), order, parse_events)
  order.send("#{user_kind}_notified_at=", now)
end
```

It's more compact and concise, but the usage of `send` might be considered ugly, and it depends on naming convention (do not dare to rename deliverer_notified_at to delivery_guy_notified_at!), so you have to choose whether or not you like it.

Comment: I would advise using `public_send` instead of `send`.